# How to Check Property Location with GIS

Tags: gis

I'm trying to find out if a particular property is located inside East Los Angeles using GIS.

GIS data uses data provided by the Census Bureau ([www.census.gov](http://www.census.gov)).

In the received data, the polygon data is imported based on the PLACEFP key value of 20802 (East Los Angeles), and the check is performed using the value.

However, when I opened the data, it was confirmed that there were about 1300 rows with the same key value.

So the question is, do all 1300 rows point to East Los Angeles or do I have to approach it in a different way?